# List of users who do not have transactions after 'x' date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query I need to create that pulls data from three different tables. Essentially the end result is to pull data for users that have not had any activity on a users' account since 07/01/2018, but they have to have an account plan as "x."  Is there a way to manipulate this query I've created to get it to display what I need it to? Maybe somehow correlate it to a count of 0 on the TRANDATE column? Very lost here and could use some help!

```
select p.ID as ID, p.LAST as LastName, p.FIRST as FirstName
From gl
inner join p
on p.ID = gl.PID
left join psp
on psp.PLANNUM = gl.ACCNUM
where gl.ACCNUM = 'x'
and psp.ACTIVE = 1
and gl.TRANDATE <= to_date('07/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
;
commit;
```

Thank you all very much and please let me know if there's anything else I can provide here.

Comment: Sample input and expected output please?

Comment: Sample input would be something like I put in my original post I think?

Expected output would be a list of users who do not have any transactional data since 07/01/2018.

Sorry, I'm not entirely sure on how to make this clearer. Essentially a list of users from table a, who have a plan on table b, that has not been used since 07/01/2018 on table c

Comment: //Sample input would be something like I put in my original post I think?// - No, sample input would be a subset of data from the table(s) you are querying, or similar.

Comment: Not really sure how to format a table on here, but I think this is what you're looking for?

Table GL

    TRANDATE                |   ACCNUM    
    6/25/2018 6:00:22 PM        22


I need it to show who hasn't used plan 22 since 07/01/2018 and the plan must be active.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299484/good-examples-of-database-questions-providing-some-sample-data-in-the-question

Answer (score 1):

You don't really specify your table structure, so I'm kinda guessing here. Does your "gl" table have more than one record per PID+ACCNUM? What are the primary keys? There are a lot of extra details you could provide.

```
select p.ID as ID, p.LAST as LastName, p.FIRST as FirstName, g.maxdate
From (select gl.PID, gl.ACCNUM, max(gl.TRANDATE) as maxdate
    from gl
    where gl.ACCNUM = 'x'
    group by gl.PID, gl.ACCNUM) g
inner join p
on p.ID = g.PID
inner join psp
on psp.PLANNUM = g.ACCNUM
and psp.ACTIVE = 1
where g.maxdate <= to_date('07/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
;
```

Also, (a) you don't need a commit on a select, and (b) a left/outer join is an inner join when you have its column in the WHERE clause (psp.ACTIVE = 1).

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use aggregation and `max()` in the `having` clause:

```
select p.ID as ID, p.LAST as LastName, p.FIRST as FirstName
from gl inner join
     p
     on p.ID = gl.PID inner join
     psp
     on psp.PLANNUM = gl.ACCNUM
where gl.ACCNUM = 'x' and psp.ACTIVE = 1
group by p.ID, p.LAST, p.FIRST
having max(gl.TRANDATE) <= date '2018-07-01';
```

Note that the `where` condition on `psp.ACTIVE` turns the outer join into an inner join, so I changed the `join` type for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Since all your display fields are from p, you can do grouping in inner queryfor the p.id which occur more than once. All the rest of ids(not in) are of your interest.

```
   select p.ID as ID, p.LAST as LastName, p.FIRST as FirstName
    From p where p.ID not in (
         select p.ID From gl
            inner join p on p.ID = gl.PID
            left join psp on psp.PLANNUM = gl.ACCNUM
            where gl.ACCNUM = 'x'
            and psp.ACTIVE = 1
            and gl.TRANDATE <= to_date('07/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
            group by p.ID
            having count(1) >= 1)
```